# Bayesian A/B testing with normal conjugate model for huge (non-normal) sample sizes

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, ab-test, conjugate-prior

I'm running an A/B test with 100k+ users per group. It consists of a lot of different metrics, some continuous, some counts... they are highly skewed, with a long tail. I'm mostly interested in the comparison of means.

I'm thinking about switching from the frequentist to Bayesian approach (easier interpretation). I'd use a conjugate prior with known variance (see the equation below from wikipedia) since my sample is so huge that I can estimate it precisely. I'd also use non-informative priors that leaves me at the end with posterior hyperparameters for the
$$\mu_x \sim Normal(\bar x, \sigma_x / \sqrt n)$$
[image: Soure Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior]

This is great news since it basically means I only need to change the interpretation and not the calculations. However, it almost seems too good to be true. What are the things I need to be careful about? For example, is there a way to check that in my case (with the data I have) is sensible to use such an approach? It's also important the approach is simple and robust (I'd like to avoid running MCMC / including covariates, at least at this stage).

Comment: Just to be clear, you assumed your data to be normally distributed, and used a flat non informative prior for the mean parameter $\mu_x$, correct ?

Comment: I don't make any assumption about the distribution of my data (it is *not* normally distributed). Flat non-informative prior, for mu, correct.